# Running code repeatedly in Ruby on Rails with Heroku for an indefinite period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am attempting to build a web application with Ruby on Rails that users site up for and get an email alert when a certain event happens.

As such, I need to be able to make an API call and then based on the JSON response, send the alert, but I need a way to have this API call happen repeatedly for an indefinite amount of time automatically. I am also using Heroku at this time if that needs to be taken into account.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sound like a cron job in plain old linux. Heroku calls this addon Scheduler. You have to define the task withing `lib/tasks/scheduler.rake`

For further information read the heroku docs for scheduler [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)

Comment: Scheduler looks perfect for Heroku, do you happen to know how one would do the same thing in an environment like AWS? Maybe something like the 'whenever' gem?

Comment: Yes, when you use an aws linux instance, you can use whenever. But whenever does only simplyfy crontab creation. So you still have to call `whenever --update-crontab` after every update of your schedule.rb. With whenever you can use the same rake task like for heroku.

Comment: From what I can tell it looks like something that runs in ruby is what I am looking for such as https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork but I'm not certain why this is the case

Comment: In the end it's your decision. I prefer cron as long as my schedule depends on no smaller unit than minutes. It's a good old linux tool. Well known and maintained.

Comment: Interesting, well, I think I'll give clockwork a go because it looks simple enough to implement, and mark your answer correct in the meantime as it answers the original.

Comment: Thx & take a look at the issue list of clockwork. Maybe some thing applys to your task.